# Fetch all normal style in ms-word file using perl script

Tags: perl, ms-word

I have Ms-Word document file (Might be *DOCX also) I need to fetch all styles used in the document using perl script.

I have tried some of the codes in search engine But I failed.

```
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Enum;
use File::Copy;
#use strict;

my $fileName = "d:\\test.doc";
my $document = Win32::OLE -> GetObject($fileName);
#Creating a new excel sheet
#my $xl_app=Win32::OLE->new('word.Application','Quit');

my $paragraphs = $document->Paragraphs();
my $enumerate = new Win32::OLE::Enum($paragraphs);

while(defined($enumerate->Next()))
{
    $style = $paragraph->{'Styles'}->{'Normal'};
    $text = $paragraph->{'Range'}->{'Text'};
    #$text =~ s/[\n\r]//g;
    #$text =~ s/\x0b/\n/g;
    #$text =~ s/\x07//g;
    print "\nStyle = $style";
    print "\nText = $text";
}
```

Input word document:

[image]

Output: As in text file `"Normal style found: Line number nn"`

Could someone help me on this one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What errors do you get? Can you provide a sample `.doc` file and expected output?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: *"Normal style found: Line number nn"* : So you want to find the line numbers for each normal style text item in the document?

Comment: Exactly champ... thats I want...

Comment: and what errors do you get with your current script?

Comment: Nothing happened..... running and closed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
use feature qw(say)
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Enum;
use constant wdFirstCharacterLineNumber => 10;
my $fn = "d:\\test.docx";
my $document = Win32::OLE->GetObject($fn) or die Win32::OLE->LastError;
my $word_app = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Word.Application') or die Win32::OLE->LastError;
my $paragraphs = $document->Paragraphs();
my $num_para = $document->Paragraphs->Count;
for my $i (1..$num_para) {
    my $paragraph = $paragraphs->Item($i);
    my $style = $paragraph->{Style}->{NameLocal};
    if ($style eq "Normal") {
        my $range = $paragraph->Range;
        $range->Select;
        my $line_no = $word_app->Selection->Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber);
        say "Normal style found: Line number $line_no";
    }
}
$document->close();
```